# Will the tulips in Holland still be in season in early June?

Tags: netherlands, event-based-effects, seasonal, parks-and-gardens, vegetation

I do understand that the Dutch tulip fields are in full bloom to be beheld in all their glory from April to early May, but will there be any stunning Tulip fields to see in early June? I know it's outside of their peak season, but what is the likelihood of there being some late-bloomers?

Where are some of the best places to view the tulip fields (or other breathtaking flower fields) in early June with or without windmills in and around the Amsterdam area?

Comment: I'm not an expert, let's wait for them. But in my experience, as you already said, it is until middle of May

Comment: You can take the train round-trip to Groningen and view from the window. Or join one of the helicopter tulip viewing tours (which are fabulous by the way). But we have great depth in Netherlands questions, wait for a bit. :)

Comment: A butterfly concerned about flowers. How poetic. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I highly doubt there will be many left in June, but someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Near Amsterdam, the place to visit would be the [Bollenstreek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duin-_en_Bollenstreek) (Bulb region), with the [Keukenhof](https://keukenhof.nl/en/) being *the* tourist highlight. This year it closes on May 21st, so you would miss that when arriving in June. By that time, most fields will be out of bloom anyway: The park uses tulips grown under climate conditions.

That said, there are more locations, conveniently listed [here](https://www.skyscanner.nl/nieuws/10-mooiste-bloemenvelden-van-nederland) (or try Google), although I don't expect there will be many tulips left there, either.

Comment: Keukenhof extends the tulip season for the park by using tulips that have been grown under climate conditions. When the park closes, the tulips in the fields will almost all be out of bloom. Mid May is already late in the year for them.

Comment: @Willeke Good point, I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Tulips are temperature triggered, they require at least a month of winter cold weather, then a couple months of warming weather.  So unless winter lasted much later than normal, fields will be bloomed out by June.

Perhaps you can find a garden or artificial environment (greenhouses, etc) where the bulbs have been forced to bloom out of season.  But it won't be the same grandeur of acres of tulips in bloom.